# How to automate updating an Excel sheet from a folder in Dropbox?

Tags: excel, auto-update, vba

My requirement is as outlined below:

a) i will be generating a CSV and I will be placing it in a shared Dropbox folder everyday at a set time on one PC.

b) I need MS Excel to check the same Dropbox folder on another PC for a new CSV everyday at the same time and update the corresponding column in the sheet with the contents of the CSV.

c) An example of this is let each column in the Excel represent a day in the month. THen each CSV would have the data for a day and I would like the script to append to the sheet as each day progresses in the month.

Kindly give pointers as to how I should be going about doing this. If in need of further clarification on above requirements, do let me know.

Thank you in advance for your time and contributions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Workbooks.Open` method to open the CSV and your destination workbook. Consider assigning them to variables, like `wbSource As Workbook` and `wbDest as Workbook`.

Then you need the `Range.Copy` method to copy the data from the CSV.

If you want to find the next available column to put the data, that will require the `Range.End` property. Something like `Cells(1,1000).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1)`.

Finally, you'll need the `Range.PasteSpecial` method to put the data on the destination sheet. Use `xlPasteAll` if you want to do a regular copy and paste. You could use the `Worksheet.Paste` method, but that requires that you select the proper cell and that's just not desirable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply Dick. Will the Workbooks.Open method also handle checking at a specific time everyday for a new file in a specified folder?

Comment: No, you would need to use `Application.OnTime` to do that.

Comment: Thanks once again Dick. Your help is most appreciated.